# indexing output of linux command in c++

Tags: c++

I want to get the ip address given url.

I am currently using this

```
        std::string i;
        std::string pingStr = (std::string)"nslookup " +"www.yahoo.com" ;
        i = system (pingStr.c_str());
```

but the output is

```
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
www.yahoo.com   canonical name = atsv2-fp-shed.wg1.b.yahoo.com.
Name:   atsv2-fp-shed.wg1.b.yahoo.com
Address: 106.10.250.10
```

**Q**: Is there anyway I can only get the **Ip address**?

Comment: Have you considered to use [`popen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) instead of `system()`?

Comment: Nope, was not aware of it, ill Check this out.

Comment: Do you want to get the address into your program or just print it by executing a different program?

Comment: Btw. I believe Sams answer is even more worth. Calling a library function is usually much less vulnerable than calling an extern program via any flavor of `fork()`/`exec()` (and most times, probably faster).

Comment: I have to get the ip adress and use it in my program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [getaddrinfo(3)](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/getaddrinfo.3.html) function to look up IP addresses, IPv4 or IPv6, in usable form.

Comment: Thanks ,Let me check This out

Comment: when i try running this , it requires 3 arguments , I only have the website url , etaddrinfo("www.yahoo.com"), am i doing this right?

Comment: No. As the documentation for `getaddrinfo()` explains, it requires four parameters. The documentation explains what each parameter should be set to. The 1st one is the address or the hostname. The 2nd one specifies what the port number will be set to, in the list of addresses that gets returned. The documentation also tells you what to specify in situations where the port number is not needed. The 3rd one is the address resolution hints pointer, and the documentation tells you what to pass when you don't need to provide hints. The 4th one is the returned list ptr. Read the documentation.

Comment: And don't forget to do what the documentation tells you to do after you finish inspecting and using the contents of the returned link list, from `getaddrinfo()`. Otherwise you will be leaking memory.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the folowing command.

```
nslookup www.yahoo.com | grep Address: |  sed -n 2p
```

grep Address gives you all lines having "address" word in them

sed gets the 2nd line of those 2

You can truncate the "Address" part of output in c++.

Comment: Kind of a strange approach in C++, calling out to tools installed on your system via the shell. We have APIs for this.